# Framework7 addnotification overlap

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-framework-7

I am using framework7 for ui. I got problem with the addnotification that overlap with the background with navbar. I already remove navbar-through but the result still same. I hope someone can help me. Thank you.[image]

```
//Part of Code
             <div class="tab" id="tab4">
                <div class="page-content">
                  <div class="content-block">
                    <p align="center" style="color:black">Waktu Operasi</p>
                  </div>         
                </div> <div class="navbar-through">
              <div class="container3">

                <div class="timeline timeline-sides">
                  <div class="timeline-item">
                    <div class="timeline-item-date">Hari <small>Bekerja</small></div>
                    <div class="timeline-item-divider"></div>
                    <div class="timeline-item-content">
                      <div class="timeline-item-inner"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="timeline-item">
                    <div class="timeline-item-date">Jam <small>Bekerja</small></div>
                    <div class="timeline-item-divider"></div>
                    <div class="timeline-item-content">
                      <div class="timeline-item-inner"> </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                    <p class="buttons"><a href="#" class="button notification-custom">Application</a></p>
                </div>
                </div>
             </div>

//Javascript
    $$('.notification-custom').on('click', function () {
        myApp.addNotification({
            title: 'Application',
            subtitle: 'Application v1.0.1',
            message: 'Supported in Android & iOS',
            media: '<img width="44" height="44" style="border-radius:100%" src="img/logo.png">'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you played with z-index on whatever html tag ? (default z-index for notification is 20000)

So try to upgrade z-index of `.notifications`